Prevent Windows 11 Sleeping
I am struggling to prevent Windows 11 from sleeping.
I have tried every combination of:
ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED

for (;;)
{
    SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
    // SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
    // SetThreadExecutionState(ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED)
    // SetThreadExecutionState(ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
    // SetThreadExecutionState(ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);

    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("The current time is: " + DateTime.Now);             
}

private const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
private const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
private const uint ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002;
private const uint ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040;

I have tried it inside the for loop and outside the for loop.
Nothing I do stops the system from sleeping after around 3 - 5 minutes.
Is there a different way to do this in Windows 11?

Within the Microsoft PowerToys exists the tool Awake. It does the same and the source code can be found here. Maybe you can compare that working code with your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436579/setthreadexecutionstatees-system-required-does-not-prevent-system-sleep-on-win
